# AjaxToolkit CalendarExtender and MaskedEditExtender - Can Not Navigate Months

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have become very frustrated with this issue and I have not found a workaround.  I am using the latest ajaxtoolkit (4.5.7.1213).  I did find another post with this issue but I have not found a resolution: http://forums.asp.net/t/1940137.aspx?Masked+Edit+Extender+and+Calendar+extender+issue

The issue can be seen by clicking the next or backwards arrow on the calendar control.  It will work one time and then on the next click it will jump back to the current month.  If I completely remove the MaskedEditExtender/Validator the functionality works perfectly fine.

Below is some basic code I used for a test.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCDate1" runat="server" Text="" Width="100" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" ID="MaskedEditExtender1" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" MaskType="None" Mask="9999/99/99" TargetControlID="txtCDate1" Filtered="/"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator runat="server" ID="MaskedEditValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtCDate1" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" Display="dynamic" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtCDate1" Format="yyyy/MM/dd"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCDate2" runat="server" Text="～"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCDate2" runat="server" Text="" Width="100" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" ID="MaskedEditExtender2" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" MaskType="None" Mask="9999/99/99" TargetControlID="txtCDate2" Filtered="/"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator runat="server" ID="MaskedEditValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtCDate2" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender2" Display="dynamic" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="CalendarExtender2" TargetControlID="txtCDate2" Format="yyyy/MM/dd"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that worked for me:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCDate1" runat="server" Text="" Width="100" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" ID="MaskedEditExtender1" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"
    MaskType="Date" Mask="9999/99/99" TargetControlID="txtCDate1" UserDateFormat="YearMonthDay">
</ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator runat="server" ID="MaskedEditValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtCDate1"
    ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" Display="dynamic" IsValidEmpty="False" InvalidValueMessage="*" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtCDate1"
    Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

#### CalendarExtender

```
Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
```

For some reason in the masked edit it shows dashes instead of slashes so when setting the date, there's a mismatch which can prevent dates from being set and I believe part of the issue when changing months. So change the format to use dashes.

#### MaskedEditValidator

```
IsValidEmpty="False" InvalidValueMessage="*"
```

Without `IsValidEmpty` set to false, I cannot change months more than one month if a date has **not** been set yet. Setting it to false makes it work... For InvalidValueMessage, put whatever error message.

#### MaskedEditExtender

```
MaskType="Date" UserDateFormat="YearMonthDay"
```

When you have a date **set** and you are trying to change months more than one month later/earlier, it seems like the masked edit extender prevents the months from changing. When you set the `MaskType` to Date, it seems to "accept" it.

Also I had to set `UserDateFormat` so that the error message set in MaskedEditValidator would not display everytime you change months or select a date. The error message would show just as you click but would hide once the change was made.

#### Conclusion

I'm not sure exactly what's causing this issue. From what I can tell from the "behaviour" the control seems to be setting a date into the mask which does not match causing the changing of months to "revert".

If anyone is interested and understands it better you can look at the source of CalendarExtender [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/Calendar/CalendarBehavior.pre.js). Switching of the months is done by the _switchMonth function.

Either way, ajax control toolkit has become even more buggy lately..

Comment: Thank you so much! I immediately looked at my production issue and not the example listed above and I made the changes you listed and they worked perfectly.  I only regret that I have but one up-vote to give. Hopefully this will help others out as well.

Comment: @Chance no problem! You could always give a bounty if you wanted to give more (if you have enough rep). But yeah hopefully this will help others!

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, it was only the IsValidEmpty="False" that was needed to be added.